# Nesting JSON in Azure Data Factory

Tags: json, etl

I'm having issues nesting JSON in Azure Data Factory.  I need to take my JSON with documents per line shown on the left and translate it to a single JSON document using an array, which is shown on the right.

[image: Raw data on the left, transformation on the right]